# What is Python's Equivalent for Excel's "Value Of" Solver?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, solver

How do I run an optimization for a particular value in Python? I'm looking for the equivalent for Excel's "Solver" tool wherein one can set the objective function as a "value of x", such that some parameters `P` are *changed* subject to `N` constraints, to get a value of `x`.

I'm aware of SciPy's optimize framework, but have only really seen applications for minimizing or maximizing x as opposed to solving for a particular value of x.

### New example

How do I solve for the return on a portfolio (`x`) such that the weights in any number of stocks `i ... K` is between 0 and 1 inclusive, and the sum of all weights  is equal to 1 (that is, `sum_weights_{i=1}^K == 1`).

I have also found a workable solution using Matrix algebra on R demonstrated in this book (https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfolioTheoryMatrix.pdf, page 13). However, have been unable to replicate this in Python.

### Previous example (please ignore)

For example, how do I solve for the number of work hours required (`P`) subject to a minimum and maximum hours (`N_1`, `N_2`) so that the profit earned is $10,000 (`x = 10_000`)?

Comment: Can you write out precise equations? That page 13 depends heavily on the earlier pages. What is the exact formula to calculate the return? What are the input variables apart from the weights?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
In [2]: P = sympy.Symbol('P', real=True, negative=False)
In [3]: sympy.solve([sympy.Eq(P * 560, 10_000), 10 < P, P < 100], P)            
Out[3]: Eq(P, 125/7)
```

Here I'm assuming the wages equal 560.

Comment: Hey @ForceBru. Thanks for your reply! I should've been more specific in the example; the problem's more of multiple workers instead of just the one. Perhaps another example will be clearer - how do I solve for the value of the "return on a portfolio" (`x`) by changing the "weights" (`P`) for N stocks, subject to the weight in any given stock being between 0 and 1 inclusive, and the sum of all weights being equal to 1?